# How can I use a projection string to refer to a current directory that has spaces in it with R (on windows)?

Tags: r, windows, path, r-sf, proj

I am doing some spatial work, and I am using a custom projection string. However, this doesn't work - it can't find the file `nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb`, and I can't work out from the documentation where it is meant to be. Putting it in my current (project) directory does not work, and nor does the `proj` folder of my sf installation.

```r
NZMG <- "+proj=nzmg  +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150  +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs"
```

I can refer to the file if I copy the file the `c:\` directory and refer to it like so:

```r
NZMG <- paste0("+proj=nzmg  +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150  +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=C:/nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs")
```

This is not a great result for portability, many people need admin access to put files in `c:\`.

I tried using `here()` to force it to look in the local directory - no joy.

```r
NZMG <- paste0("+proj=nzmg  +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150  +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=", here(), "/nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs")

> NZMG #note spaces in path that is returned
[1] "+proj=nzmg  +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150  +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=C:/Users/nealm/OneDrive - DairyNZ Limited/Desktop/dairynz/NZMS1_conversion/nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs"
```

I think it is due to the spaces in the path.

I confirmed this by using dir `/X` in the windows command prompt to find and substitute in the short (no spaces) name for the OneDrive folder, which is `ONEDRI~1`, and the resulting projection string works:

Context for short path: https://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file

```r
NZMG <- "+proj=nzmg  +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150  +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=C:/Users/nealm/ONEDRI~1/Desktop/dairynz/NZMS1_conversion/nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs"
```

So, I can make it work on my computer, but it is not very portable. Either:

1. I need to find the place where the file will be found (and instruct users to put it there, if they can),
   OR,
2. Find a way of using `here()` or something similar to apply the short (no spaces) folder names on Windows, from R, in a neat way.

Or maybe I am missing something even easier?

Comment: The answer to question 1 appears to be, for me, copy the file nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb from this project folder, to the "proj" folder, in your "rgdal" folder, wherever your R packages are saved. Then it should work. I'm still interested in the second solution, which might be better, or if there are easy approaches to copy the file automatically to the correct location that makes solution 1 a better experience for the user.

Comment: It looks like there may be an option with utils::shortPathName(). Hat tip, krlmlr https://github.com/r-lib/here/issues/82#issuecomment-1154644055

Comment: what version of R are you using? I had issues with path before - although it involved not spaces but non-ASCII characters - and upgrading to 4.2 (and UCRT support) helped

Comment: I was running R4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(here)
library(utils)
```

### Option 1, put the .gsb file in the right place

The answer is, copy the file nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb from this project folder, to the "proj" folder, in your "rgdal" folder, wherever your R packages are saved. Then it should work.

```
NZMG <- "+proj=nzmg  +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150  +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs"
NZMG
# n.b. it looks like NZMG needs this file - nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb
# Available at LINZ link below (and now copied into this repo, see file list).
# https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/download-geodetic-software/gd2000it-download
```

### Option 2, use short path name to point to location in this project

Note `here::here()` gives current location in the project, and wrapping that in `utils::shortPathName()` takes out the spaces so the projection works

```
NZMG <- paste0("+proj=nzmg  +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150  +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=", utils::shortPathName(here::here()), "/nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs")
NZMG
```